# When Kardur, Doomscourge is active, do myriad-empowered creatures create tokens and deal damage to the Kardur player upon attacking?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

In an EDH game, when an opponent controls [Kardur, Doomscourge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kardur%2C%20Doomscourge) with its enters-the-battlefield (ETB) ability activated, if I attack another opponent with my creatures that have myriad (courtesy of [Legion Loyalty](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Legion%20Loyalty)), does myriad generate attacking tokens for the Kardur player, and does this also result in dealing damage to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Myriad doesn't care about Kardur's ability. Myriad tokens are created for every opponent even if they have Kardur's ability active.**

Kardur's ability creates *requirements* that force your creatures to attack, and attack another player, if able. However, if an effect (such as Myriad) creates tokens that are already attacking, those creature tokens skipped the "declare attackers" part of combat and are thus unaffected by the requirement to attack another player. Same goes for effects that put a creature card onto the battlefield tapped and attacking, such as [Winota, Joiner of Forces](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Winota%2C%20Joiner%20of%20Forces).

> 508.4c A creature that’s put onto the battlefield attacking or that is stated to be attacking isn’t affected by requirements or restrictions that apply to the declaration of attackers.

Once a creature is attacking by whatever means, it will participate in combat and deal damage as usual.

Comment: Ninjutsu is a bad example, since the ninja attacks the same player/walker that the creature it replaced was attacking per rule 702.49c: A ninjutsu ability may be activated only while a creature on the battlefield is unblocked (see rule 509.1h). The creature with ninjutsu is put onto the battlefield unblocked. It will be attacking the same player, planeswalker, or battle as the creature that was returned to its owner’s hand.

Comment: If they didn't skip being declared as attackers, there'd be an infinite loop, as the copies would have myriad and would also spawn copies.

Comment: Doesn't Kardur's ability create two _requirements_, not restrictions? If a creature can't attack another player (in a two-player game, or other players have Propaganda effects) it must attack Kardur's controller

Comment: @MatthewJensen thanks, fixed.